# Libgdx change velocity of moveTo action

Tags: libgdx

I am trying to create physics for a ball in Libgdx. The ball starts moving after a pan and everytime the ball collides with a wall, a moveTo action is added to it. But my ball moves with a constant velocity (action time = distance/velocity). I want my ball movement to get slower smoothly.

Here is my method for calculating velocity

`private float velocity(float panDistance) {
        float coefficent = 0.3f;
        return panDistance / coefficent;
    }`

in act method of the Ball I decrement velocity

`@Override
    public void act(float delta) {
        super.act(delta);
        if (velocity < 100 && velocity > 0) {
            ballImage.clearActions();
        }
     velocity -= 3f*delta;
 }`

When gesture detector detects a pan the method below is called.

`public void moveTheBall(float tanX, float tanY) {
        if (ballImage.getActions().size == 0) {
            motionVector = (int) (tanX / Math.abs(tanX));
            motionAngleTan = tanY / tanX;
            panDistance = (float) Math.sqrt((tanX * tanX) + (tanY * tanY));
            velocity = velocity(panDistance);
            recursivelyAddActions(motionVector);
        }
    }`

in recursivelyAddActions() method

`private void recursivelyAddActions(int vectorDirection) {
    // AFTER SOME CALCULATIONS
    distance = (float) Math.sqrt(((predictionX - ballStartingPosX) * (predictionX - ballStartingPosX)) + ((predictionY - ballStartingPosY) * (predictionY - ballStartingPosY)));
        moveToAction = Actions.moveTo(predictionX, predictionY, distance / velocity);
        ballImage.addAction(moveToAction);
    }`

this is not smooth and this does not work good. I need an advice to make this work better. Thank you.

Comment: Show us the code for how you've tried to solve this problem so far.

Comment: It's hard to get the full context when we see only these snippets. Can you show us where these two pieces of code get called relative to one another in the flow of your program, and where the velocity variable gets used?